# At what point does the MongoDB C# driver open a connection?

Tags: mongodb, c#

I'm having a problem with lots of connections being opened to the mongo db.

The readme on the [Github page for the C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/) gives the following code:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("foo");
var collection = database.GetCollection("bar");

collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("Name", "Jack"));

foreach(var document in collection.FindAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine(document["Name"]);
}
```

At what point does the driver open the connection to the server? Is it at the `GetServer()` method or is it the `Insert()` method?

I know that we should have a static object for the client, but should we also have a static object for the server and database as well?

Comment: Couldn't you find out with some debug print statements (or break points) and a check on current connections? Or, have the connection fail by making the mongod unavailable and see where it throws an error.

Comment: Connections are opened at the Insert method. There is a pool underneath the driver, so "lots of connections" is a bit ambiguous. Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer... but the server connection is created at this point:

```
 var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Everything else is just getting references for various objects.

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: Could you place a more relevant link ? 
How do you know that this is the point where mongo opens a new connection ?

Answer (score 0):

While using the latest MongoDB drivers for C#, the connection happens at the actual database operation. For eg. db.Collection.Find() or at db.collection.InsertOne().

```
{
    //code for initialization
    //for localhost connection there is no need to specify the db server url and port.
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/"); 
    var db = client.GetDatabase("TestDb"); 
    Collection = db.GetCollection<T>("testCollection"); 
 }
//Code for db operations
{

   //The connection happens here.
   var collection = db.Collection;
   //Your find operation
   var model = collection.Find(Builders<Model>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
   //Your insert operation
   collection.InsertOne(Model);
}
```

I found this out after I stopped my mongod server and debugged the code with breakpoint. Initialization happened smoothly but error was thrown at db operation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you find this info ? 
How do you know this to be true ?